# Power template coding

Tags: c++

I want to write a template function for exponentiation called `pow()`

and I want to write specialization on the template functions..

-If the exponent is an integer:
If the base is 2: use bitwise shifting
Otherwise: exponentiate using a loop

-Otherwise:
Use `std::pow()` and use the `std::common_type` of the operands as 
   the return type.

This is for the codejudge, I tried numerous times with adjustment but I can't make it work.

this is my code:

```
namespace math {
template <typename T, typename U>
T Pow(const T& base,const U& exponent) {
    {
        return std::pow(base, exponent);
    }
};

template <typename T>
T inline pow(const T& base, int exponent) {
    T x = 1;
    if (base == 2) {
        return (base << exponent) / 2;
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
            x = base * x;
        }
        return x;
    }

};
template <typename t>
t inline pow(double x, const t y)
{
    return std::pow(x, y);
}
```

}

which should calculate this code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "pow.h"

int main() {

    // integer base, integer exponent
    std::cout << math::pow(12,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(2, 12) << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(12, 2.1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << math::pow(12.1231, 4) << std::endl;
    int x;
        std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

for each answer that should be:

Output:

```
  144
  4096
  184.621
  21600.04969
```

but mine gives:

```
144
4096
144 (or error!)
error!
```

Comment: Yours doesn't compile [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26b7d6a6621451aa): Typo `Pow` vs `pow`, and ambiguous call anyway.

Comment: `(base << exponent) / 2` should simply be `1u << exponent`.

Comment: *"I want to write specialization"*. You don't, you write overloads :-) (and you can't as partial specializations are not possible for template functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
namespace math {

    template <typename T>
    T pow(const T& base, int exponent) {
        T x = 1;
        if (base == 2) {
            return 1U << exponent;
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
                x = base * x;
            }
            return x;
        }

    }

    template <typename T>
    std::common_type_t<double, T> pow(T x, double y)
    {
        return std::pow(x, y);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/njsXCq)

Answer (score 0):

You really do *not* want to compute integer exponent by repeatedly multiplying by the base. That's not only very slow (for all but the smallest exponents), but also [numerically unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability), so it'll be inaccurate. Also - what about negative powers? It seems to me like you haven't quite thought this thing out.

But to address your concrete question: I'd try to avoid relying on the intricacies of overload set resolution. Write a single:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T Pow(const T& base, const U& exponent);
```

and dispatch exactly how you like it. For example, using

```
if (std::is_integral_v<U>) { /* call one variant */ }
else { /* call another variant */ }
```

And if you use `if constexpr`, you might just be able to have all your code within the same function.